# Comparing the ingredients of various lists of enums

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to compare the ingredients of two Enum-Lists on a button click and I want to receive different messages based on the match.

More precisely: I have different recipes at hand and if my selected ingredients match with one of them I will receive a special message. If my ingredients don't match with anything I will receive a standard message.

Here is what I tried but did't worked properly:

```
public void DrinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var recipe in RecipeList)
    {
        List<Ingredients> copy = new List<Ingredients>(selectedPotion.MyIngredients);

        if (copy.Count == recipe.Recipe.Count)
        {
            for (int i = copy.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                Ingredients item = selectedPotion.MyIngredients[i];

                if (recipe.Recipe.Contains(item))
                {
                    copy.Remove(item);
                }
                if (copy.Count == 0)
                {
                    recipe.DrinkEffect();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Doesn't taste like anything!", "Announcement!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Here is what I tried but did't worked properly.` In what way did it not work?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: This code produces multiple messageboxes rather than one, which are not destined for chosen ingredients. The problem is how to change this code to produce only one answer based on my chosen ingredients:
- If chosen ingredients match one of the recipes a chosen messageBox.

Comment: - If not match to receive a default messageBox.

Comment: The code is clumsy because it uses the wrong collection type.  A recipe for a mixed drink is a set, not a list.  The order does not matter.  Use HashSet instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Linq's `All` to check if both Lists of Ingredients contain the same elements:

```
public void DrinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (selectedPotion == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a potion to drink", "Help Window", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        return;
    }

    foreach (var recipe in RecipeList)
    {
        bool equalIngredients = recipe.Recipe.All(selectedPotion.MyIngredients.Contains) &&
                                    recipe.Recipe.Count == selectedPotion.MyIngredients.Count;

        if (equalIngredients)
        {
            recipe.DrinkEffect();
            return;
        }
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Doesn't taste like anything!", "Announcement!",
                        MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
}
```

This will loop over all items in RecipeList and check if the item's `Recipe` equals `selectedPotion.MyIngredients`. If so it will call the `DrinkEffect()` method on the current item, otherwise it displays the "Doesn't taste like anything!"-MessageBox.

A few remarks:

- `recipe.Recipe` just looks wrong, maybe go for a more precise naming
- The code currently doesn't check if `selectedPotion` is `null` or not, i see potential for a NullReferenceException

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I received a "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error. Do you know why?

Comment: @Erm where do you receive it? And i stated in my remarks that i see potential for a NullReferenceException for `selectedPotion`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on answers his my final solution: (I still received "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error.)

```
    public void DrinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        foreach (var recipe in RecipeList)
        {               
            bool equalIngredients = recipe.Recipe.All(selectedPotion.MyIngredients.Contains) && recipe.Recipe.Count == selectedPotion.MyIngredients.Count;

            if (equalIngredients)
            {
                recipe.DrinkEffect();
                goto NextStep;
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Doesn't taste like anything!", "Announcement!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        NextStep: return;      
    }
```

Comment: Please don't use `goto` like this. Check my answer i updated it, it now does exactly the same as this without the need for a `goto`.

Comment: But your answer produce the last message in any case. I dont want to see that message if the recipe is correct.

Comment: Nope, check my answer again, i changed it. It now also includes your null check.

Comment: Wavv, it really works. But I am confused, there is no condition for last messageBox, and it doesn't run eachtime.

Answer (score 0):

Here is latest:

```
    public void DrinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (selectedPotion == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a potion to drink", "Help Window", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var recipe in RecipeList)
            {
                bool equalIngredients = recipe.Recipe.All(selectedPotion.MyIngredients.Contains) && recipe.Recipe.Count == selectedPotion.MyIngredients.Count;

                if (equalIngredients)
                {
                    recipe.DrinkEffect();
                    goto NextStep;
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Doesn't taste like anything!", "Announcement!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        NextStep: return;
        }
    }
```